# Python - Plot one column of data from multiple text files into single graph

Tags: python, plot

I am very new to Python

Trying to plot one column of data from multiple similar files (see below)

```
#0  Date-time:  20/02/2015 22:50            
#1  Recorder:   35X1078         
#2  File type:  0           
#3  Columns:    7           
#4  Channels:   4           
#5  Field separation:   1           
#6  Decimal point:  1           
#7  Date def.:  0   2       
#8  Time def.:  0           
#9  Channel 1:  Temperature(°C) Temp(°C)    3   1
#10 Channel 2:  Depth(m)    Depth(m)    2   2
#11 Reconvertion:   0           
#14 Channel 3:  Pitch(°)    Pitch(°)    1   1
#18 Channel 4:  Roll(°) Roll(°) 1   1
#19 Line color: 1   2   3   4
1 20-02-15 12:00:00 8.615 -2.64 92.3 88.8                   
2 20-02-15 12:00:01 8.615 -2.64 92.1 89.1                   
3 20-02-15 12:00:02 8.615 -2.64 92.1 87.2                   
4 20-02-15 12:00:03 8.615 -2.64 92.6 89.6                   
5 20-02-15 12:00:04 8.615 -2.64 91.9 91.5                   
6 20-02-15 12:00:05 8.615 -2.64 91.9 88.7                   
7 20-02-15 12:00:06 8.615 -2.64 92.1 89.7                   
8 20-02-15 12:00:07 8.615 -2.64 92.5 87.2                   
9 20-02-15 12:00:08 8.615 -2.66 92.1 87.6                   
10 20-02-15 12:00:09 8.615 -2.64 92.9 87.4
```

Data has a number of header rows to be ignored and ignore first column

My code for plotting a single file is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sys


print 'loading & plotting: '+sys.argv[1]+'.txt'
data=pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1]+'.txt',delimiter='\s',skiprows=17,names=['index','date','time','temp','pressure','pitch','roll'],infer_datetime_format=True)

fig,axes = plt.subplots(4,1)
data.plot('time','temp',ax=axes[0])
axes[0].set_ylabel('temperature $^\circ$C')
data.plot('time','pressure',ax=axes[1])
axes[1].set_ylabel('pressure (Bar)')
data.plot('time','pitch',ax=axes[2])
axes[2].set_ylabel('pitch $^\circ$')
data.plot('time','roll',ax=axes[3])
axes[3].set_ylabel('roll $^\circ$')
fig.suptitle('Data from Star Oddi pitch + roll sensor X1078: %s'%(data['date'][0]))

fig.savefig('X1078_uimage.png',bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

I know the layout of my graphs is rubbish, I can tidy that myself, but I now want to plot multiple files on to the same graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to repeat plot calls inside a loop while changing your data, but leaving the figure creation and saving out of the loop.

If you often deal with lists of files, glob module is good and easy.

```
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

files = glob("*.txt")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for f in files:
    print("Current file is"+f)
    #your csv loading into data   
    data.plot('time','temp',ax=axes[0])   

#outside of the for loop
plt.savefig("myplots.png")
```